# Editing css-properties using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to use adjust CSS-properties using jQuery:

- the menu_div should be the same width as the screen:

  ```
  $("#menu").css({width: (theWidth - 10)});
  ```
- the gallery_img should be at the left side of this div, the contact_img should be on the right side:

  ```
  $("#gallery_img").css({left: 0 + 'px'});
  $("#contact_img").css({right: 0 + 'px');
  ```

The menu-div and the images both have position: absolute. What am I doing wrong? All images are displayed on top of each other.

Comment: If it's `0px` you can simply use `0`.

Comment: How are you defining "theWidth" and you said you want the menu width the same as the screen width so why the - 10? Plus as Pekka says we need to see some other code. Your HTML and CSS of the #menu and side bits would help.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in your code:

```
$("#contact_img").css({right: 0 + 'px');
//                                    ^ missing closing brace }
```

Also, your CSS width assignment for the `#menu` element isn't followed by "px", which invalidates the rule and may cause it to fail in some browsers:

```
// Incorrect
$("#menu").css({width: (theWidth - 10)}); 

// Corrent
$("#menu").css({width: (theWidth - 10) + "px" });
```

Note that, if you're planning on using a numeric literal you may as well just use a string on its own and avoid the concatenation.  You can also pass the css property and value as separate arguments:

```
$("#contact_img").css({right: '0px'});
$("#contact_img").css('right', '0px');
```

Comment: Good catch, missed the brace. but there's also a missing unit in the #menu bit. Should have a `+ 'px'` as well most likely.

Comment: @MarcB: Good catch yourself :-)  Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have some missing braces, perhaps a simpler way to do it would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var theWidth = $(window).width();
        $("#menu").css('width', theWidth - 10);
        $("#gallery_img").css('left', 0);
        $("#contact_img").css('right', 0);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute will do that.  your left for the gallery_img should be 0px... then your contact img's left attribute should be the left for the #menu + #menu's width in px.

if you do not specify the left attribute with a position absolute you will ultimately just stack everything.